# unexpected attribute error in python object

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, suds

I'm parsing objects returned by the suds client from a Web Services SOAP API

I have a list of attributeObjects, like

```
(defectStateAttributeValueDataObj){
   attributeDefinitionId = 
      (attributeDefinitionIdDataObj){
         name = "Comment"
      }
   attributeValueId = 
      (attributeValueIdDataObj){
         name = "Owner changed because of default owner assignment specified in the component map"
      }
}
```

and

```
(defectStateAttributeValueDataObj){
   attributeDefinitionId = 
      (attributeDefinitionIdDataObj){
         name = "OwnerName"
      }
   attributeValueId = 
      (attributeValueIdDataObj){
         name = "Schmoe, Joe"
      }
 }
```

I use the following loop to extract key/value pairs:

```
for defect in myDefectsPage.mergedDefects :
   print defect.cid,
   for attribute in defect.defectStateAttributeValues:
       print attribute
       attr= attribute.attributeDefinitionId.name
       val=attribute.attributeValueId.name
       print attr,'=',val,
       print ""
```

(The above objects are results of the print attribute command)

This will work  as expected for EVERY attribute, except the one where attribute.attributeDefinitionId.name == "Comment"

for that one I get the

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File , line 63, in 
    val=attribute.attributeValueId.name
AttributeError: 'Text' object has no attribute 'name'

which is strange, because if I use
    val=attribute.attributeValueId #.name
it will print

Commment =  (attributeValueIdDataObj){
             name = "Owner changed because of default owner assignment specified in the component map"
          }

So it looks like it IS an attributeValueIdDataObj and DOES have a name attribute.

I used the suds DEBUG logging and the XML return elements look exactly the same regardless of what the attribute.attributeDefinitionId.name is.

I have no idea how it changes into a 'Text' object when trying to access the name attribute

Any ideas?

Comment: workaround:                 
valueId=attribute.attributeValueId
if hasattr(valueId, 'name'):              
    val=valueId.name
else:
    val=valueId

worked, and it showed that indeed it IS an attributeValueIdDataObj and it DOES have a name attribute, just hasattr() handles the AttributeError exception while the getattr() or .name doesn't.
Weird...

Answer (score 0):

On further examination (and printing out the type of the returned object when exception happened) this was a bug in the web services SOAP server.

When a Comment was empty, it returned an

```
<attributeValueId/>
```

tag,

instead of the proper

```
 <attributeValueId>
      <name/>
 </attributeValueId>
```

object. so it resulted in sax.Text object instead of the suds.attributeValueIdDataObj object

So no python or suds mystery to solve.

Sorry for the false alarm...